# Unknown class and NSUnknownKeyException in Xcode 10 GM

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, simulator, xcode10

I have downloaded the Xcode 10 GM and my app crashes immediately when running in Simulator. Xcode says:

```
Unknown class _TtC7App-Name14ViewController in Interface Builder file.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f944440c880> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundImage.'
```

However when I open my project in Xcode 9, there is no error and my app works perfectly. 
I searched for this problem and I tried everything that other people suggested on stackoverflow. From checking all the storyboard object and constraint connections, to making sure that the Classes are right and Inherit Module From Target is checked. I also tried „Erase All Content And Settings“ in Simulator and deleting the DerivedData folder. Removing the backgroundImage in Storyboard and code didn’t help, because then I got the same error but with another object from the same ViewController.

Does anyone have the same issue and found a solution?

**EDIT:** When I add a new View Controller and set it to "is initial ViewController", the view does load in Simulator. As soon as I add a swift file and set the Class in Interface Builder for that new ViewController, I get the Unknown Class warning. And when I add a label or any object, I get: Unknown class AND NSUnknownKeyException. So there's definitely nothing wrong with a specific ViewController or object. If someone had the same problem, please help me. I can't do anything anymore with this project :(

[ViewController Identity Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jup8e.png)

[Storyboard Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzffu.png)

Comment: Let's concentrate on the Identity inspector. It is clear that your setting for the view controller's class in Interface Builder for ViewController is not being obeyed. Do you remember to hit Return? When you do, do you see the Module filled in? Did you check Inherit Module From Target?

Comment: I uploaded two screenshots that show how it looks like at the moment. I tried deleting the Class in Identity Inspector and entering it again, but no success.

Comment: I'm curious about the module name `VOYAGE_` in those screen shots. Does your app's name end in a punctuation mark?

Comment: My app's name ends with an é, but I didn't have problems with that in Xcode 8 and  9.

Comment: Bingo. I am suggesting that you do have problems with that in Xcode 10. This would explain everything. Your module's name is not `VOYAGE_` so the class cannot be found on that basis. Make sense?

Comment: So what do you recommend me to do? Can I remove the underscore, but keep the app's name that the user sees? And if so, how should I do it?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Product Module Name is a build setting; you could change it. I'm not sure if that will fix anything, but you could try it. Having done that, go back to Identity inspector and enter ViewController _again_ and see if we get the right module name this time. I've never tried this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the project name is not the same as the display name. You may want the display name to have an é and that's fine. But you should not use anything but ascii in the project name. It is not user-facing so changing it is fine. And that might solve the problem.

Comment: I renamed the app via Target's File Inspector. When I pressed enter in the Class field for every ViewController it changed the module to VOYAGE and removed the Inherit Module From Target checkmark. My app is working again. I hope that this problem is solved now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Well, in fact what you did, I think, is rename the project, as I suggested. This also automatically changes a bunch of other stuff (you should have seen a dialog confirming this). — But you may now have changed your app's display name to something you don't like, so be sure to fix that. Edit the Target, go to the General pane, and Display Name is the first thing you'll see. This user-facing so fix it if needed.

Comment: Added our result as an actual answer! This could be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your project name (and all that follows from that) is not pure ascii alphanumeric (in particular, it contains a diacritic, an "é" character). This can mess things up in subtle ways. I don't know why Xcode 10 chokes on this but Xcode 9 doesn't, but there it is.

The solution is to change the project name and allow the renaming cascade that this causes. Then edit the Display Name so that it's the way you want it; that's the user-facing name of the app, and an "é" in that is perfectly fine.